# Парсинг json координат

Tags: c#, json, парсер

Пытаюсь спарсить координаты с Json, но всё парсится в один объект, а нужно распарсить это дело по x и y:
Данные для парсинга ниже:

```
{"coordinates":[[[38.220892,47.3053966],[38.2925345,47.3059301],[38.3109722,47.3060674],[38.3360399,47.3062541],[38.3360168,47.3059565]]]}
```

Собственно, как можно с помощью, например NewtonSoft распарсить все значения и десериализовать их в объект
Coordinates с полями x и y?

Comment: Я могу вытащить массив объектов с координатами. Меня интересует, как распарсить значения и присвоить их X и Y.

Comment: Ну раз вы распарсили, то в чем проблема? Вот у вас на руках массив с координатами, где [0] это x, а [1] это y, вот и берите эти данные и используйте как вам угодно. Можете хоть написать .Select(x => new { X = x[0], Y = x[1] } ); и получите в нужном формате данные, но нужно-ли оно?

Comment: Я не уточнил. К сожалению данные с координатами спарсились в один объект, а не разбились на массивы. 

Делал так:  
public class Geojson
    {
        public object[] coordinates { get; set; }
    }

Если делать object[][] -возникает ошибка, которая говорит о том, что невозможно привести тип к Object

Comment: Тогда почему вы врёте, говоря что смогли получить данные? Ссылка выше показывает как работать с json, советую почитать, а после этого вы поймёте, что надо делать структуру классов и коллекции, а не просто object...